# How to allow self-service updates of recurring contribution credit card details with IATS?

Tags: recurring-contributions, iats

Is it possible to use a message template to send an email reminder asking recurring donors to update their credit card when it fails?

Answer (score 3):

This works for us using IATS Payments Extension, not sure how it would be applied with other payment processors. Fuzion tokens is also required for the {contribution.latest_recur_contribution_id} token.

Simply send contact this link:
/civicrm/contribute/updatebilling?reset=1&crid={contribution.latest_recur_contribution_id}&{contact.checksum}

Comment: How do you handle a scenario where a donor might have a recurring profile for a membership and an additional recurring contribution? Ideally the token would for the most recent recurring contribution ID that is linked to a membership?

Comment: I think you'd have to add a couple specific tokens to cover that use case (which wouldn't be hard to do). Maybe one for membership contributions and one for non-membership contributions. The latest_recur_contribution_id token just returns the recurring contribution with the highest ID (the most recently created one). If this is only a small number of cases, you can just grab the recurring contribution ID manually and insert it.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to set up a Civi rule that sends an email for someone to update their card if a recurring payment fails.  It seems like this token + civirules approach might work. I've never coded a token, will have to check that out.

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/selfservicetokens