# Allow self-service updating of contribution and membership recurring payments

Tags: recurring-contributions

The issue is very similar to this: [How to allow self-service updates of recurring contribution credit card details with IATS?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42680/how-to-allow-self-service-updates-of-recurring-contribution-credit-card-details/42681?noredirect=1#comment51106_42681) and even discussed in the commentary.

What is the best way to have CiviCRM automatically send people an email when their recurring payments fail, for either membership or contribution? Ideally, this would happen via CiviRules so other actions could be taken.

In the above post, CiviCRM can't handle the use-case of someone having multiple recurring contributions that may need updating because the token only targets the latest one. It was suggested a custom extension be made to solve this use case which is something I'm exploring and looking for someone to do.

I've found this: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/selfservicetokens which requires patches to CivicRM (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/22450) which remains unclear to me if it's a good idea to do.

Any thoughts? I mean, all we want is this:

Recurring payment profile runs, fails, then triggers an email to be sent to customer with a link to update their card or cancel the profile.

Ideally, all steps of this would be customizable via UI, but that's not an absolute need.  Much appreciate your insight and expertise and commentary.

Comment: I don't recall if this covers recurring - i suspect not - and also more geared to notifying admin of a failure, but there may be something here you can re-use or add to: https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.incompletepaymentalert

Comment: Thanks Pete! Do you know of any developer who would want a one off project making such a tool or extension? I'd love to see it in CiviCRM, because the reality is once you have a large # of recurring contributions, doing things manually isn't an option and you lose sales

Comment: I would expect several folk might be up for doing this, how about you re-ask over at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/town-square. We (Fuzion) could do it but it would not be in the near future I expect

Comment: @Zachary It turned I have some code written (and tested) - for now it is just an ugly iats extension hack, going to commit a patch. Please ping me if you're interested.

Comment: @yurg interested!

Comment: @Zachary Great, how do I contact you please?

Comment: zkrebs at gmail